# Convert xml format to data frame in r

Tags: r, xml

I have an aquarium monitoring system that logs data in XML format, which I retrieve locally. Here is an example of the structure;

```
<datalog>
    <record>
        <date>20210301 00:00</date>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1Temp</name>
            <type>Temperature</type>
            <value>10.4</value>
        </probe>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1Sal</name>
            <type>Salinity</type>
            <value>28.0</value>
        </probe>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1pH</name>
            <type>pH</type>
            <value>8.0</value>
        </probe>
    </record>
    <record>
        <date>20210301 00:01</date>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1Temp</name>
            <type>Temperature</type>
            <value>10.5</value>
        </probe>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1Sal</name>
            <type>Salinity</type>
            <value>28.1</value>
        </probe>
        <probe>
            <name>Tank1pH</name>
            <type>pH</type>
            <value>8.0</value>
        </probe>
    </record>
</datalog>
```

This is a very simplified example, records are logged every minute for 24 hours so this chunk is repeated 1440 times per day. There are also a lot more probes per record logged than the three examples above.

I want to turn this into a data frame with the columns "date", "name", "type", "value". I have gone through similar questions on the web but none of the solutions work for me. I think it is because the probes are all nested within the date and examples are more 'simple' and don't explain how to deal with nested structures.

So far I can get R to read the data from the system (it is connected to a router that is only accessible locally) but once in R I am lost. I tried using the following code;

`dataframe <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(data.20210225, c("//record/date", "//record/probe")))`

which produces a data frame that looks like;

| text | name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210301 00:00 | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | Tank1Temp | Temperature | 10.4 |
| NA | Tank1Sal | Salinity | 28.0 |
| NA | Tank1pH | pH | 8.0 |
| 20210301 00:01 | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | Tank1Temp | Temperature | 10.5 |
| NA | Tank1Sal | Salinity | 28.1 |
| NA | Tank1pH | pH | 8.0 |

This works in terms of saving the data but it is not very usable for analysis due to all of the NAs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

How do I turn this XML into a data frame? Or make the data frame I have more analysis friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider extending your data frame handling with by building a list of individual `<record>` level data frames with `xpathApply` for final `rbind` compilation at the end:

```r
recds <- xpathApply(data.20210225, "//record", function(x) {
             # ADD CLEANED NEW date COLUMN  
             df <- within(xmlToDataFrame(x), { date <- text[1] })

             # RE-ORDER/SUBSET COLS, DROP FIRST ROW, RESET ROWNAMES
             data.frame(df[-1, c("date", "name", "type", "value")], row.names=NULL)
         })

final_df <- do.call(rbind, recds)
final_df
#             date      name        type value
# 1 20210301 00:00 Tank1Temp Temperature  10.4
# 2 20210301 00:00  Tank1Sal    Salinity  28.0
# 3 20210301 00:00   Tank1pH          pH   8.0
# 4 20210301 00:01 Tank1Temp Temperature  10.5
# 5 20210301 00:01  Tank1Sal    Salinity  28.1
# 6 20210301 00:01   Tank1pH          pH   8.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I saw many examples and similar questions but seeing it with my data labels has helped me understand it.